# jquery validation prevent input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form that adds grades to my db table. I am using jquery validation to control wether the input is a range between 1-5 or if it's empty or not. However my jquery doesn't seem to work since it still allows empyt fields to be inserted or wrong input... Any idea why and how I can fix this?

My form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="insertGrade.php" method="post" id="gradeStudent" name="gradeStudent">
   <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Betyg:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <p><input id="betyg" name="gradeStudent" type="text"></p>
            <?php
                if(isset($_GET['courseId'])) {
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='courseId' value='" . $_GET['courseId'] . "'>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Sätt betyg">
    </div>
</form>
```

My jquery:

```
    <script>
    $("#gradeStudent").validate({
      rules: {
        betyg: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 1,
          max: 5,
          min: 1
        }
      }
      messages: {
        betyg: {
          required: "Mata in ett betyg",
          maxlength: "Betyget kan endast vara een siffra mellan 1 till fem",
          max: "Mata in ett giltigt värde som är mindre än eller lika med 5.",
          min: "Mata in ett värde som är större än eller lika med 1"
        }
      }
    });//jquery validation 
  </script>
```

Thank you for helping~

Comment: Put comma between properties `{rules:{...} , messages:{...}}`

Comment: It's still not working, do you have any other idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: change `betyg` in `rules` and `messages` to `gradeStudent` . It works with `input` `name` attribute . [http://jsbin.com/sicaje/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/sicaje/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you so much for helping me! :D